# OR-Tools CP-SAT solver: is it possible to name a constraint like in GUROBI

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, cp-sat

I try to implement cp model with OR-tools CP-SAT solver. Please, is it possible to name constraints for being able to manage conflict later like for variables:
`t_var[i] = model.NewBoolVar(f"affect_{i}")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setter:

```
ct = model.Add(x == 2).WithName("my_ct")
```

Getter:

```
ct_name = ct.Name()
```

Comment: Thanks, it is good, 'model.Add(z_var[edge_iter] for adge_iter in ens_edges if edge_iter[0] == v).WithName(f"ct_{v}")'

Answer (score -1):

```
C1 = model.addConstrs(<<expr>>, name = 'C1'+str(i))
```

Comment: the question is about the CP-SAT api, not the Gurobi one.

Comment: I think that this formulation is for GUROBI